# Im new to threads and semaphores and i can seem to understand why my code wont work, any help will be appreciated

Tags: c, multithreading, semaphore

I'm trying to make a code that prints <one><two><three> with semaphores, but the code won't run, and I cant find my mistake.

I also tried `pthread_join`, but it's the same: it won't print, no matter what.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

sem_t f1, f2, f3;

int done = 1;

void *threadfunc(void *n) {
    int a = 0;

    while (1) {
        if ((int)*(int *)n == 1) {
            //printf("1st THREAD!\n");
            printf("<ONE>");
            sem_wait(&f1);
        } else if ((int)*(int *)n == 2) {
            //printf("2st THREAD!\n");
            printf("<TWO>");
            sem_wait(&f2);
        } else {
            //printf("3st THREAD!\n");
            printf("<THREE>");
            sem_wait(&f3);
        }

        //}

        if (done == 3) {
            done = 1;
            sem_post(&f1);
        } else if (done == 1) {
            done = 2;
            sem_post(&f2);
        } else if (done == 2) {
            done = 3;
            sem_post(&f3);
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    pthread_t tid1, tid2, tid3;
    int n1 = 1, n2 = 2, n3 = 3;

    for (;;) {
        // Create 3 threads
        pthread_create(&tid1, NULL, threadfunc, (void *)&n1);
        sleep(1);

        pthread_create(&tid2, NULL, threadfunc, (void *)&n2);
        sleep(1);

        pthread_create(&tid3, NULL, threadfunc, (void *)&n3);
        sleep(1);

        // infinite loop to avoid exit of a program/process
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Expected output: `ONE TWO THREE ONE TWO THREE` *etc*.

Actual output: none

Comment: you are creating constantly threads instead of just 3 thread, so perhaps think about removing 'for(;;)' and use `pthread_join(tidx, NULL);`  in main for each of your threads

Comment: You might want to initialize your semaphores using `sem_init` before your create the threads.

Comment: can you show me how to initialize the semaphores because im new to this and i dont know exactly how im gonna do this,thanks in advance.

Comment: "*im new to this*" what about reading related documentation, for example `man sem_init`?

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple issues in your code:

- You launch not just three threads, but an unbounded number of them.  A comment in your code suggests that the point of that may be to prevent the main thread from exiting, but that's a completely inappropriate way to solve the problem.  The usual approach would be to `pthread_join()` your threads, or maybe simply to `sigsuspend()` or `pause()`.
- You use your semaphores without initializing them.  As a result, the behavior of all your semaphore functions is undefined.  You must use `sem_init()` at the beginning of the program to initialize each semaphore's state, including, but not limited to, its initial value.  Probably one of them should be initialized with value 1, and the others with value 0.
- The structure of your thread function is odd.  Normally one wait wait for the semaphore *first*, then do whatever work, then post the next semaphore last.  But even if you arrange the semaphore operations as you have, I see no point whatever to variable `done`.  Your usage of that is completely redundant with your use of `n`.  The two convey the same information: the identity of the thread.
- If you want the data printed by each thread to appear immediately, then you should `fflush(stdout)` after each `printf()` call.
- If you want a delay between prints then you should put that in the thread function, not in `main()`.